# Webex crashing/lockup Firefox / Chromium Browsers - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, firefox, java, chromium, webex

When launching webex from firefox or chromium browser. Browser freezes and stops responding.  Browser process must be killed to exit. Please help me troubleshoot this.

Here are my setup details and error messages I have gathered below:

Setup:  Ubuntu 12.10 and all software updates installed.  From Java Console:  Java Plug-in 1.6.0_43   Using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

running file `which java javac` shows the following:

```
/usr/bin/java:  symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'
/usr/bin/javac: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/javac'
```

I have several Java's loaded:   running command `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
produces:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1082      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1082      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1081      manual
```

The Java console produces the following output when attempting to start webex:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_43
Using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = /home/tony

----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:97)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:84)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.<init>(CachedJarURLConnection.java:58)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:18)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(DeployURLClassPath.java:797)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(DeployURLClassPath.java:678)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:745)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(DeployURLClassPath.java:737)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(DeployURLClassPath.java:699)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:407)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:396)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:373)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(DeployURLClassPath.java:237)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:1006)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:995)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:129)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:263)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:193)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:253)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:193)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:703)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3031)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509ExtendedDeployTrustManager.<init>(X509ExtendedDeployTrustManager.java:113)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler$Initializer$1.run(Handler.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler$Initializer.<clinit>(Handler.java:40)
    ... 31 more
Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```